# Solr query only returns Id's

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I have wanting to import data from a table and index it using solr..
I am using solr-tomcat admin panel.

But whenever I query it returns to me only the id's and *value*.
I have also tried adding FIELDS to fl , but that also does not help.

here is my data-config.xml file:

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
 driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/{DB_NAME}"
 user="{DB_USER}"
 password="{DB_PASSS}"
 />
 <document>
 <entity name="id" query="select s3_location,file_name from video">
 <field column="s3_location" name="s3_location"/>
 <field column="file_name" name="file_name"/>
 </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Is there any way to get the above s3_location and file_name fields also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the actual field names in the fl parameter or use * to indicate all fields. Also, please note that the fields must have been defined with `stored=true` in your schema.xml file for them to be returned/visible during a query.

- `fl=id,s3_location,file_name`
- `fl=*`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `stored=true` in my schema.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are importing the data at all? If you start with empty index, do you get anything?

The reason I ask is because you are not mapping the id field explicitly. Now, I believe there is implicit mapping of the fields by Jdbc data source based on names, but relying on it is risky when you are just starting.

Otherwise, like Paige said, make sure you defined those fields in your schema and that they are actually stored.